# What does "bock" mean?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

What does "bock" mean?

[image]

> Such a crowd, chanting in the roadway and scoffing on the pavement, I could not hope to penetrate, and dreading to go **bock** and farther from home again, and deciding on the spur of the moment, I ran up the white steps of a house facing the Museum railings, and stood there until the crowd should have passed

Also, why "should have passed" and not just "passed"?

Comment: Is this from *The Invisible Man* by HG Wells?  It looks like a typo for **back**.  Every available copy on the web seems to say *back*.

Comment: @stangdon I added a picture

Comment: Certainly a typo for **back**. I suggest asking a new question (or editing this one) to ask about *should have passed*.